# sublime text - Calculations with selected numbers

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm looking for an package to calculate an expresion with as input a selected number in Sublime Text 2.
For example:
I would like to increment each selected number by 2. "|" is the end of each selection.

```
label2 | =Label(top,bg="#BFBFBF",height=1,text="freq [Hz]")
label2 | .place(x=420,y=320)
label3 | =Label(top,bg="#BFBFBF",height=1,text="d.c.[%]")
label3 | .place(x=520,y=320)
slider1 | =Scale(top,variable=dutycycle_var,length=300,resolution=1,command=set_pwm)
slider1 | .place(x=500,y=5)
slider1 | .set(50)
```

I want to be able to change the variable names quickly to:

```
label4 |=Label(top,bg="#BFBFBF",height=1,text="freq [Hz]")
label4 |.place(x=420,y=320)
label5 |=Label(top,bg="#BFBFBF",height=1,text="d.c.[%]")
label5 |.place(x=520,y=320)
slider3 | =Scale(top,variable=dutycycle_var,length=300,resolution=1,command=set_pwm)
slider3 |.place(x=500,y=5)
slider3 |.set(50)
```

And if this is possible i'm curious if other operations are also possible like *, sqrt, power ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SelectionEvaluator**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Selection%20Evaluator) allows the following inline calculations:

- `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^`
- `sin`, `cos`, `abs`, `trunc`, `round`, `sgn`
- `E`, `e`, `pi`

[image: Demo]

Comment: Nice! thats so handy! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following package seems to accomplish what you are looking for: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/inc-dec-value-st2-and-st3/1931

[image]

> Increase / decrease of numbers (integer and fractional), dates, hex
>   color values, opposite relations or cycled enumerations on the
>   configured value and a bonus - string actions (upper, lower,
>   capitalize)